# specification of rendering HTML mail

Tags: html, email, html-email, email-client

> Is there somewhere I can find specifications of rendering html emails
>   for specific email clients?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for CSS compatability and something like Litmus or Email on Acid to test display across each email client.

There is no standard in HTML email, so not only can the result of each tag or style vary, but also which tags/styles are available for use with what can change.

a couple good links on designing HTML emails:

https://www.exacttarget.com/products/email-marketing/email-design-toolkit

http://labs.actionrocket.co/the-hybrid-coding-approach-2

Answer (score 0):

They should render HTML content the same way that it would render in a browser, so I suppose in that sense, yes: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/